# Firefox vs Chrome runtime.sendMessage: uncaught exception: Object

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I'm adapting a Chrome extension to Firefox. Eventhough https://www.extensiontest.com/ says my extension is compatible there are still errors.

One of them is the `runtime.SendMessage` function which I call in my `content_script.js` to send a message to `background.js`.

This method works as expected on Chrome/Brave but yield an `uncaught exception: Object` in Firefox.

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: "update-title",
    options: { title, url },
});
```

Looking at both API docs I cannot understand what's wrong for Firefox since they are supposed to be similar  ([Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage), [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage))

Comment: The first call won't run in Chrome/Brave as its third parameter is [completely incorrect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage). If it works in that extension then it must have redefined the standard function somehow. The second call is correct and it should work so the error may be caused by something else: try commenting out everything else to isolate the problem.

Comment: Ok I edited my question, let's just focus on the previous thing, thanks. I cannot understand what FF is trying to tell me with "uncaught exception: Object" what shall I understand from this message to debug?

Comment: There's no such message in current [source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=%22uncaught+exception%22&path=-test&case=true&regexp=false) of Firefox so it may be something the extension itself is printing so try searching its sources. Maybe it's the site that prints it. Maybe it's another extension. Try isolating the cause by removing every other factor.

Comment: I'll open an other question then @wOxxOm it seems like it's something else indeed...